# application does not show adwhirl ads

Tags: android, adwhirl

I created a simple application that shows add using ad whirl .it does not show any ad
i added logcat file

thanks in advance

```
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619): Caught IOException in fetchConfig()
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619): java.net.UnknownHostException: mob.adwhirl.com
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager.java:221)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:293)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:114)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:229)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-18 15:08:55.940: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be fatal.
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(AdWhirlManager.java:279)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager.java:246)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:293)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:114)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:229)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-18 15:08:55.970: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619): Caught IOException in fetchConfig()
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619): java.net.UnknownHostException: mob.adwhirl.com
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager.java:221)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:293)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:114)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:229)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-18 15:09:26.019: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be fatal.
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(AdWhirlManager.java:279)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager.java:246)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:293)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:114)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:229)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-18 15:09:26.029: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(619):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: It seems like *"java.net.UnknownHostException: mob.adwhirl.com"* may be the root cause. Check you internet connection. And also do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` your application manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: mob.adwhirl.com
```

That means that the url doesn't exist or that it returns 404. Try to open it with a browser and you see the 404 error page.

Comment: Note that to get a 404 the host has to be found in the first place. You would get a *host not fond* error otherwise. I think they just don't have an index page for the root of the site. That's not necessarily an issue.

Comment: @Kariyachan What do you get when you visit `http://mob.adwhirl.com` from the Android browser?

Comment: @Kariyachan And you still get an UnknownHostException?

Comment: @ Alexandre Jasmin,yes i got same exception

Comment: @ Alexandre Jasmin, it is beacause of spelling mistake in manifest file thanks 4 help

Answer (score 2):

Please have a close look at the code. For AdWhirl integration with AdMob in Android Platform.

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
<meta-data android:value="719308a6f08e4d68bf3158161fb45f99"
    android:name="ADWHIRL_KEY" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In Layout put a LinearLayout where you want to show the AdWhirl ads.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/AdLayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in Java File:

```
private LineaLayout mAdLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
      mAdLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.AdLayout);
      AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams = 
      new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      int mAdWidth = 320;
      int mAdHeight = 75;
      AdWhirlTargeting.setAge(23);
      AdWhirlTargeting.setGender(AdWhirlTargeting.Gender.MALE);
      AdWhirlTargeting.setKeywords("ketan patel android");
      AdWhirlTargeting.setPostalCode("94123");
      AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(false);
      DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
      mAdHeight = mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
      float mDensity = mDisplayMetrics.density;
      mAdWidth = mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
      mAdHeight = (int) (mAdHeight * mDensity);
      AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(Usage.this,
      "719308a6f08e4d68bf3158161fb45f99");
      adWhirlLayout.setAdWhirlInterface(Usage.this);
      adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth(mAdWidth);
      adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight(mAdHeight);
      adWhirlLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
      mAdLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
      mAdLayout.addView(adWhirlLayout, adWhirlLayoutParams);
      mAdLayout.invalidate();
}

**Here 719308a6f08e4d68bf3158161fb45f99 is the SDK Key from AdWhirl Account.
**Put AdWhirlSDK_Android_3.0.0.jar and GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.0.jar 
files into libs folder and reference those using 
Java BuildPath from the properties.
```

Thanks.

I hope this can help you.